# why {{#markdown}} is not working?

Tags: yaml, markdown, yeoman, handlebars.js, assemble

I am using Assemble.io and I am trying to use the {{#markdown}} tag to display some content but it does not work and I have tried everything.

This is the content of my file (index.hbs):

```
<div>
   {{#markdown}}
    # My Blog Post
    > This is my first blog post!
    Whoo hoo!
   {{/markdown}}
</div>
```

And this is how I actually see the page:

[image]

I have tried to install Handlebars helpers (https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) but nothing changed.

If I use

```
{{md '../path/to/markdown.md'}}
```

I am able to see the markdown of that file correctly.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the whitespace that @james-wing mentions in his answer is the issue. Have you tried some of the other whitespace control methods mentioned for Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#whitespace-control ? Also, what version of assemble are you using?

Comment: @doowb Thanks doowb. I have removed any spaces but nothing changes. It is not rendering as markdown but is coming up inside <pre><code>xxx</code></pre> as a plain text. It's driving me crazy. Assemble version is: 0.4.42 (i believe it's the last one)

Comment: <pre><code>xxx</code></pre> tells me that it is rendering as markdown but as a code block because assemble doesn't add anything like that. Do you have a repo with maybe just the one file that reproduces the issue?  Also, if you want to try using Handlebars 3, switch to `grunt-assemble`. That will be the code base for the grunt plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it is rendering markdown, but interpreting your markdown as a code sample because it is indented. Try removing all indentation:

```
{{#markdown}}
# My Blog Post
> This is my first blog post!
Whoo hoo!
{{/markdown}}
```

In fact, this is visible right here in SO:

```
# My Blog Post
> This is my first blog post!
Whoo hoo!
```

vs

## My Blog Post

> This is my first blog post!
>   Whoo hoo!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I had to indent it on here only because it was recognised as markdown by the editor. Surely this editor works better than my local one lol.. I have tried anyway but no luck :-( ..I believe there is a problem with something else. So annoying

Comment: I have removed any spaces but nothing changes. It is not rendering as markdown but is coming up inside <pre><code>xxx</code></pre> as a plain text. Is it expected to generate those html tags?

Comment: Try starting from a simpler markdown blog, maybe without whitespace like `{{#markdown}}#Hello, Markdown!{{/markdown}}`.  If that works, build up from there.